# How do I get an image from a WIA camera?

Tags: wia

I installed the sample driver for a WIA camera.

I don't know how to get an image from it.

What should I do?

Comment: How about telling us what language/platform you are using?

Comment: Read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wiascriptingdotnet.aspx) one for a pretty good look at what you need to do

Answer (score 1):

Use WIA Stream Snapshot filter in [GraphEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphEdit).

If you want to do it programmatically, you may use [WIA interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368(VS.85).aspx).